# How to replay a recursive macro recording once?

Tags: vim

I started recording by typing qw.

Then, I pressed @w to replay the search,movement and replacement.

A couple of seconds after, I saw my replay in an infinite loop.

How can I only repaly my recording only once ?

Is this possible ? Should I use another vim command ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually search and replace is done with `:s`.  For example, to replace all *foo* with *bar*

```
:%s/foo/bar/g
```

See `:help :s` for more info.

To end a macro, type `q` in normal mode.  So, a macro to move right, delete the next three characters, and move down would be typed as follows

```
qql3xjq
```

Then to replay the macro, `@q` or `3@q` to execute it three times (`:help q`).  Adding `@q` to the macro would make it recursive.